# Firebase Crashlytics won't activate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have run my app on a device and in simulator with no success of updating the Firebase Crashlytics system.

I am not getting any errors, and I know that it's installed because it says the version number (4.5.0) in console.

Also Firebase Analytics is working.

I have followed the install guide to a T and also tried to force crash it by creating a SwiftUI button and using

```
fatalError()
```

Which seems to not fully crash the app, but more freeze the app.

I am wondering how I can trace this issue with SwiftUI and Firebase.

Comment: Have you tried running the app with the flag `-FIRDebugEnabled`?

Comment: I got it to work, had to run the app on my phone and not via Xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#test_it_out), if you're going to use the Xcode Simulator, you must detach the Xcode debugger at runtime by launching the app directly from the Simulator and not Xcode. Xcode automatically attaches its debugger if you launch from Xcode to a Simulator, blocking Crashlytics from being able to see exceptions/crashes.

Answer (score 3):

In addition of doing what the accepted answer recommends and I believe this is something new from Xcode 12.+. You need to uncheck the two checkboxes below the script window (at least once - you may tick them back up once registered with firebase). This (as stated) forces the script to run and therefore to communicate with firebase... [the checkboxes unticked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA4rK.png)